# UWP - getting the list of Bluetooth devices in dropdown list

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

i am trying to get the list of paired Bluetooth devices in to the drop-down list on my UWP. I know i need to use FindAllAsync class and i thought I had it right but for some reason i cant get the list to show the BT devices.

bellow is my code, can you please point in what I am missing here:

```
namespace ArduinoRobotControl
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection;
    private DeviceInformation selectedDevice;
    private RfcommDeviceService deviceService;

    public string deviceName = "Dev B"; // Specify the device name to be selected; You can find the device name from the webb under bluetooth 

    StreamSocket streamSocket = new StreamSocket();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializeRfcommServer();

    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        //var BTDevinfo = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
        var BTDevinfo =  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort), new string[] { "System.Devices.AepService.AepId" });
        selectorComboBox.ItemsSource = deviceCollection;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToDevice();
    }

    private async void InitializeRfcommServer()
    {
        try
        {
            string device1 = RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
            deviceCollection = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(device1);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            errorStatus.Text = exception.Message;
        }
    }

    private async void ConnectToDevice()
    {
        foreach (var item in deviceCollection)
        {
            if (item.Name == deviceName)
            {
                selectedDevice = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (selectedDevice == null)
        {
            errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            errorStatus.Text = "Cannot find the device specified; Please check the device name";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            deviceService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(selectedDevice.Id);

            if (deviceService != null)
            {
                //connect the socket   
                try
                {
                    await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(deviceService.ConnectionHostName, deviceService.ConnectionServiceName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    errorStatus.Text = "Cannot connect bluetooth device:" + ex.Message;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                errorStatus.Text = "Didn't find the specified bluetooth device";
            }
        }



    }
```

I believe the problem is somewhere within these few lines:

```
        var BTDevinfo =  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
        selectorComboBox.ItemsSource = deviceCollection;
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot understand why you specify the `selectorComboBox.ItemsSource` in `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` handler? This event occurs when the currently selected item changes. Why not specify `selectorComboBox.ItemsSource` in `InitializeRfcommServer` method?

For example:

```
private async void InitializeRfcommServer()
{
    try
    {
        string device1 = RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
        deviceCollection = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(device1);
        selectorComboBox.ItemsSource = deviceCollection;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

        errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        errorStatus.Text = exception.Message;
    }
}
```

And here is XAML code for combo box in which im trying to pull the device list:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="selectorComboBox" 
                          Margin="845,533,0,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          SelectionChanged="selectorComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

***[Updated on 2017/12/15]***

You need to bind DeviceInformation object's Name projerty in "ComboBox.ItemTemplate'. See above my edited XAML code.

Besides, it seems that you're not very familiar with Binding. I suggested that you could read the Binding relevant document first. See this [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)

Here is a MS official code sample [Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) for your details.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your response. This seems to get me closer to what i need.  I made adjustments as you suggested and now in drop down menu i can see a string but its saying : "Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation". I have few devices paired with my laptop but non of them is showing in the list.

Comment: @Slavisha How did you bind `DeviceInformation` to your combobox? I want to see your xaml page.

Comment: Xie, i posted the code above. Do you need to see entire XAML code ir that piece  is sufficient?

Comment: @Xie thank you so much this actually did work. You are awesome.